# Codename One - addSubmitButtons method of Validator class changes button style

Tags: ios, codenameone

I'm developing a Codename One app for iOS.
I defined a button as follows:

```
Button signUpButton = new Button();
signUpButton.getAllStyles().setBorder(Border.createEmpty());
signUpButton.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
signUpButton.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0x9d1710);
signUpButton.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0x848484);
signUpButton.getAllStyles().setMargin(Component.LEFT, 4);
signUpButton.getAllStyles().setMargin(Component.RIGHT, 4);
signUpButton.setCapsText(true);
signUpButton.setText("Conferma");
```

After that, I created a Validator, I added some constraits to other text fields and then I added the button to the validator:

```
validator.addSubmitButtons(signUpButton);
```

The addSubmitButtons method changes the style I set for the button (in particular, the margins and size changed).

I also tried to set the style I want to the button after the addSubmitButtons method, but it seems it doesn't consider it. It happens on simulator and on device too.

This is what happens without calling the addSubmitButtons method:

[image]

This is what happens calling the addSubmitButtons method:

[image]

How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 1):

When the validation doesn't pass the button is set to disabled so the the disabled style is picked of the 4 styles.

I'm guessing here but I'm assuming that the margin/padding of the disabled style is still set in pixels instead of millimeters for the native theme. If you explicitly set all styles to use millimeters it should work.

Comment: Before calling the setMargin method, I added this: signUpButton.getAllStyles().setMarginUnit(Style.UNIT_TYPE_DIPS); Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem. Is that the correct way to set millimeters as units?

Comment: That should work, can you isolate a reproducible standalone test case?